# Are there different combinatorial species with the same symmetry type?

Tags: combinatorics, category-theory, group-actions

First off: for my purposes, let $\sf B$ be the category of finite sets with bijections, and ${\sf B}_n$ the subcategory of sets with cardinality $n$, and define a combinatorial species to be a functor $F:{\sf B}_n\to{\sf B}$. This captures the idea of building "structures" on $n$-sets. Write $[n]=\{1,\cdots,n\}$. Every permutation $[n]\to[n]$ induces a corresponding map $F[n]\to F[n]$, so we always have that $F[n]$ is an $S_n$-set.

Can we have nonisomorphic species $F\not\cong G$ for which $F[n]\cong G[n]$ as $S_n$-sets?

In practice, the only way I've been able to prove two species are nonisomorphic (e.g. $S_k\times\binom{-}{k}$ versus ${\rm injhom}(k,-)$) is to show that the corresponding sets $F[n]$ and $G[n]$ are nonisomorphic as $S_n$-sets - eventually I figured out this was the key fact I was using to prove nonisomorphism - but I haven't thought of anything else to accomplish this.

If the isomorphism type of $F[n]$ as an $S_n$-set was enough to determine $F$ it would mean we could "build" a unique (up to isomorphism) species for every $S_n$-set, and this strikes me as impossible because of how "unbased" a generic set $X$ is, although this is a fuzzy intuition at the moment.

Note this is beyond finding inequivariant $S_n$-sets with the same cycle index polynomial, since the isomorphism $F[n]\cong G[n]$ as $S_n$-sets will imply identical cycle index polynomials.

Ideas or comments?

Comment: Note that $B_n$ is equivalent to the symmetric group $S_n$ as category.

Comment: The notation $B_n$ is very unfortunate, since it usually refers to the braid group on $n$ strands. Better use $\Sigma_n$ or $\mathbb{P}_n$. See http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/permutation+groupoid

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg In a few sources on combinatorial species, $\cal B$ is used for the category of finite sets with bijections, and so $B_n$ would make sense for this subcategory. I don't think braid groups have ever showed up in combinatorial species contexts, so I'm not worried. I've even seen $\Sigma_n$ used for the symmetric group in the context of defining braid groups...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the category of finite sets with bijections is equivalent to the permutation groupoid $\coprod_{n \geq 0} S_n$, two combinatorial species are isomorphic if and only if the corresponding $S_n$-sets are isomorphic for all $n$. If you do not believe this, here is a direct argument: For each $n$, let $\alpha_n : F([n]) \to G([n])$ be an isomorphism of $S_n$-sets. We claim that for every bijection $f : [n] \to [m]$ we have $\alpha_m \circ F(f) = G(f) \circ \alpha_n$ ($*$). Since $f$ is bijective, we have $n=m$. But since $\alpha_n$ is an isomorphism of $S_n$-sets, we have $\alpha_n \circ F(f) = G(f) \circ \alpha_n$, and we are done. Now if $X$ is any finite set, choose some bijection $f : X \to [n]$ and define $\alpha_X : F(X) \to G(X)$ by $\alpha_X := G(f)^{-1} \circ \alpha_n \circ F(f)$. Using ($*$) one checks that $\alpha_X$ is (1) independent from $f$, (2) natural in $X$.

Comment: Ah, yes. In fact I even constructed this $\alpha_X$, and rereading my scratchwork it seems I proved $\alpha_X$ was independent of $f$ without even realizing it... welp. Anywho, follow-up: if we define sum and product of species as $(F+G)X=FX\sqcup GX$ and $(F\cdot G)X=FX\times GX$ then isomorphism classes of species ${\sf B}_n\to{\sf B}$ becomes a semiring, and then formal differences of species classes becomes essentially the Burnside ring of $S_n$ (the Grothendieck construction), right? Interesting.

Comment: It is the Burnside ring of the groupoid $\coprod_n S_n$.

Comment: Well, I'm talking about functors ${\sf B}_n\to{\sf B}$ (whereas species elsewhere are always defined as ${\sf B}\to{\sf B}$). But this seems right, and it means I'll have some other things to think about later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my ideas and comments, explained for the less initiated reader.

Note that the expression "transport of structures" is misused in the theory of species. The thing transported by functoriality is *only and only* the subjacent symmetry of a structure - and this is why we are looking to permutation groups and cycle indices.

The first two permutation groups with the same cycle index are 8T18 and 8T22 in Maple, so the cycle index does not define a species but the question is beyond this: then what defines a species up to isomorphism ?  As shown in the answer, only the symmetry matters. This is somehow unbelievable given the word "structure" is used by tradition instead of "symmetry".

For example, take the Chvátal graph and an octogon with four marked edges. They have the same subjacent species, and *nothing else in common* - where it comes to labeling.

[image: Chvatal graph]